# insert/update shared tables jdbctemplate

Tags: sql, spring, hsqldb, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

The problem is that my domain contains list of elements from other two tables. I will illustrate it with an example:

Customer:

```
public class Customer {
  String name;
  List<Product> products;
  List<Bag> bags;
}
```

Product:

```
public class Product {
  String description;
}
```

Box:

```
public class Box {
  String description;
}
```

And my tables will look like that
`Customer: cid pk, name;  Product desc, cid fk;  Box desc, cid fk;`

I can implement a `SELECT` query using joins, as well a `DELETE` with 3 database operations for the three tables, but I'm stuck with the implementation of an `INSERT` and especially an `UPDATE`. Iterating through the lists of boxes and products and manually insert/update them is a solution, but not an efficient one. I want to minimize the number of database operations as much as possible (best case 3 I think). Any Suggestions?

I am using HSQLDB and Spring, which means JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use [batchUpdate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.List-), first for the Customers, then for the Products and Boxes. You are correct that you need at least 3 database operations, no way around that.